# C# MySqlParameter problem

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, mysql-parameter

(int) faultsGroup  is 0 or 1 but i always get this error: Column 'FaultGroup' cannot be null

Does anyone tell me why? Syntax looks ok.

```
MySqlCommand cmdAdd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Faults (" +
        "  FaultGroup, Text, Date, IP" +
        ") VALUES (" +
        "  @FaultGroup, @Text, @Date, @IP" +
        ")", conn);

MySqlParameter paramFaultGroup = new MySqlParameter("@FaultGroup", MySqlDbType.Int32);
FaultsGroup faultsGroup = (FaultsGroup) Enum.Parse(typeof (FaultsGroup), myFault.FaultGroup);
paramFaultGroup.Value = (int) faultsGroup;
cmdAdd.Parameters.Add(paramFaultGroup);

cmdAdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: You should accept answers for your questions by clicking the hollow checkmark next to an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used MySql for about 6 months (thankfully migrated off to Sql Server) but, try changing your @ symbols for ?'s, as if memory serves, that's the correct convention with MySql, so:

```
MySqlCommand cmdAdd = new MySqlCommand(
       "INSERT INTO Faults (FaultGroup, Text, Date, IP)"
       + " VALUES (?FaultGroup, ?Text, ?Date, ?IP)",
       conn);

MySqlParameter paramFaultGroup = new MySqlParameter("?FaultGroup", MySqlDbType.Int32);
FaultsGroup faultsGroup = (FaultsGroup) Enum.Parse(typeof (FaultsGroup), myFault.FaultGroup);
paramFaultGroup.Value = (int) faultsGroup;
cmdAdd.Parameters.Add(paramFaultGroup);

cmdAdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Actually, the '@' symbol works fine, at least for the MySQL ADO.Net connector (which I assume the OP is using).

Comment: problem was in version of ado.net connector. i was using 5.1.7 now i am using v6.

Thx all for help

Comment: how can i know about the version ?