# How to use a SqlDataReader result as a MySqlParameter value

Tags: c#, mysql-connector

I'm moving tables from a SQL Server DB to a MySQL DB programmatically.

I've got a SqlDataReader populated with a table's fields values, and I would like to insert them into the corresponding MySQL table. There aren't primary key and auto increment problems on destination table.

What I'm missing is howo to convert a SqlDataReader field value to a MySqlParameter value.
This is a snippet of my code:

```
Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT a,b,c,d,e FROM sqlTable";
Cmd.Prepare();
dr = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    MySqlConnection mySqlConn = new MySqlConnection(mySQLConnString);
    mySqlConn.Open();
    mySqlCmd.Connection = mySqlConn;
    mySqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO mysqlTable VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ";
    for (int k = 0; k < dr.FieldCount; k++)
    {
         mySqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter(dr[k].ToString(), dr[k]));
    }
...
```

A fatal error occurs on the line, without any detail.

```
mySqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter(dr[k].ToString(), dr[k]));
```

I cannot understand how to set `dr[k]` value acceptable for MySQL.

Comment: How are you observing this fatal error? Does the application just stop without *any* exception?

Comment: What is the exception message? Did you try to debug the code? Did you try to see what is sent to the server, eg with a profiler? In any case, your code uses the reader's value as the name of the parameter which is definitely wrong

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# MySqlParameter problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322274/c-sharp-mysqlparameter-problem)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've got some problems in debugging due to SQL Server and MySQL not reachable concurrently from my dev environment. That syntax was working in a similar context but with ODBCParameter instead of MySqlParameter.

Comment: @kiks73 ODBC is not Connector/.NET. Perhaps the MySQL ODBC driver ignores the parameter names but that's irrelevant. The code is wrong in both cases. The first string parameter in the constructor of both classes is the parameter's name. If it worked with [OdbcParameter(string,object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh148b89.aspx), it was by accident

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok, I understand. Just trying this way: mySqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter(dr.GetName(k), dr.GetValue(k)));